# Eloquent ORM object relashionship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, illuminate-container

i have two tables. School and Student.

When i fetch all Students

```
Student::all()->toJson();
```

I get a response with

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "school_id": 1,
    "name": "Jhon"
  }
]
```

But actually i would like to receive

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "school": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "name": "Jhon"
  }
]
```

I know i could do

```
Student::with(['school']);
```

But then it do an extra query to school table, which is not necessary, as i only need the school id, and not all other attributes.

Comment: You'll have to specify your own `toJson` method in order to get this kind of transformation. If Eloquent did this kind of transformation on an underscore, and there was a field `full_name` should eloquent do `[ { "full": { "name": "John Smith" }, "id": 2 } ]`?

Comment: No it shouldn't. It should do `method_exists(Student, 'full')` first. For example, on `school_id`, we have `public function school() {
  return $this->belongsTo('\Project\Model\School');
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `toArray` method in your model. The same thing also would be possible with `toJson`, but `toArray` gets called by `toJson` and in my opinion its nicer to do such stuff in `toArray`

```
class Student extends Eloquent {

    public function toArray($options = 0){
        $this->school = ['id' => $this->school_id];
        unset($this->school_id);

        return parent::toArray($options);
    }
}
```

#### Edit

To keep the model the same and only change to output (which is probably better)

```
public function toArray($options = 0){
    $array = parent::toArray($options);
    $array['school'] = ['id' => $array['school_id']];
    unset($array['school_id']);
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: It works but i'm not comfortable with modifying the model itself

Comment: That looks better. I can mix your answer with @Raphael_'s to make it generic. But i'm trying to figure if it's better to create a base model and override toArray() or use the collection way that he said.

Comment: Both ways work. If you're never gonna need the original json, I'd recommend extending the (Base) model itself. And you'll need to extend the model anyway to overwrite the `newCollection` method. So, yeah...

Comment: I personally don't see an advantage of using `transform` over `toArray` (but maybe I'm missing something)
However the cool thing about `toArray` is, that it is also used by a lot of Laravel code. For example `Response::json($students)` will automatically call `toArray`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Illuminate\Support\Collection`'s `transform` method for a more automated solution:

```
$students = Student::all();

$students->transform(function($el) {
    $el = $el->toArray();

    foreach ($el as $k => $v) {
        if (substr($k, -3) === '_id') {
            $el[substr($k, 0, -3)]['id'] = $v;

            unset($el[$k]);
        }
    }

    return $el;
});


return $students;
```

If you're going to call this multiple times (which I assume you will), the best would be to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and add a method to do that. Then edit the `newCollection` method on your base model to use your new extended class.

Comment: This looks like a good option. Did you mean `newCollection`? Also, your code doesn't work when i want to bring other stuff from the relashionship, `$el[substr($k, 0, -3)]['id'] = $v;` fixes it.

Comment: Yep, `newCollection`, my bad.